# Nginx - Serve static html content with whitespace in filename

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I use this setting to serve static html files:

```
server {
    root /var/www/static_html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html =404;
        autoindex on;
    }
}
```

Now if a filename contains whitespace `"spam spam.html"` the response is "404 Not Found"

In the access.log:

```
"GET /spam%20spam.html HTTP/1.1" 404
```

Is it possible to serve these files?

Comment: The above configuration seems to work fine. What operating system are you using?

Comment: I have a similarly basic configuration for one of my static sites and it works fine. Do other files with no spaces work fine? What do you web server access and error logs say?

Comment: It works fine for files with no whitespace. There are no errors in the error.log. The access.log just shows a normal 404 not found. It runs on Debian 8

Comment: What version of `nginx` you use? I tried on my CentOS 7 and nginx/1.12.0. Everything works as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bumped into the same issue when trying to setup NGINX to serve WebP files from the same filename as JPG/PNG's and certain files were containing spaces. The reason why it happens like this is:

- space cannot be used inside of an URL and browsers replace it automatically inside the URL with `%20`, as you might be aware​
- the `$uri` variable in this case will contain the link with `%20` as you can see from the logs
- when NGINX is looking for the file with `%20` in its name on the disk, it will not find it, because on disk it is stored with space and not with `%20`, therefore it will result in a 404.

A potential way of getting this to work is to do a replacement of the `%20` with a space and the only way of achieving this that comes to my mind is to use something like OpenRestly's Lua NGINX Module:

[https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module​​](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B)

Then, **after this is properly installed and configured (not very easy!)**, you might try something like this, just before `try_files`:

```
access_by_lua_block {
        ngx.var.uri = string.gsub(ngx.var.uri, "%20", " ")
}
```

This isn't actually tested, it's just an idea. If there are better ways to achieve this, I'm open to check them!
​​